# Yii2 in Apache subdirectory can't hide directory name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2

I deployed yii2 on a **www** subdirectory.

#### root .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xxx\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### yii directory .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.xxx\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) www.xxx.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

#### UrlManager

```
'urlManager' => [
  'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
  'showScriptName' => false,
]
```

then use **www.xxx.com/www/site/about** is fine，

but without the subdirectory **www**, all controller can't visit, eg: use **www.xxx.com/site/about** can't visit, is redirect to index,

but the **www.xxx.com/requirements.php** can visit

how do hide **/www/** in the path.